# Basic SQL Query Construction Regarding Dates as a Parameter in Toad

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation, date-arithmetic

I am very new to SQL and am having issues understanding some if its syntax. Before you tag this as a duplicate, I have spent quite some time reading other questions similar to mine.

What I need to do is get the SUM of product produced each month between July and December of 2012 as a total and by individual month.

My table has columns for date of production and total items produced that day. The production date in the data base is stored as '5/21/2013 11:23:45 AM' for example

TABLE is named 'FIRST_CONVEYOR_ROW'

COLUMNS are named 'AMNT_OF_PRODUCT' and PROD_DATE

I need something along the lines of:

```
       SELECT SUM(AMNT_OF_PRODUCT) AS MONTHLYTOTAL FROM FIRST_CONVEYOR_ROW
       FOR EVERY MONTH BETWEEN JULY AND DECEMBER OF 2012
```

Obviously the second line to the query is incorrect, but it conveys what I need.

The output Im looking for would be something like:

JULY: 4tons

AUG:  6tons

.....
TOTAL 30 tons.

I can get the overall total easily, but when I try to add date ranges it blows up on me.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Read more about the functions you can use with dates.
And also the "group by" function
With "group by" you can group you're data by month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE FIRST_CONVEYOR_ROW (
  AMNT_OF_PRODUCT NUMBER,
  PROD_DATE       date
);

INSERT INTO FIRST_CONVEYOR_ROW
values(7, to_date('01/07/2012','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO FIRST_CONVEYOR_ROW
values(4, to_date('02/07/2012','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO FIRST_CONVEYOR_ROW
values(2, to_date('02/08/2012','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO FIRST_CONVEYOR_ROW
values(3, to_date('04/08/2012','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO FIRST_CONVEYOR_ROW
values(9, to_date('04/12/2012','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO FIRST_CONVEYOR_ROW
values(6, to_date('04/01/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'));
COMMIT;
```

The query is:

```
select to_char(PROD_DATE, 'Month') as product_month, sum(AMNT_OF_PRODUCT) as MONTHLYTOTAL
from   FIRST_CONVEYOR_ROW
where  PROD_DATE between to_date('01/07/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('31/12/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
group by ROLLUP (to_char(PROD_DATE, 'Month'))
order by to_date(product_month, 'Month')
;
```

result of query:

```
PRODUCT_MONTH           MONTHLYTOTAL
----------------------- ------------
July                              11
August                             5
December                           9
                                  25
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The way you have the query laid out makes it really easy for me to understand the syntax behind it.